# How to apply an expression on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I gets the expression and new column name as parameters.

```
aggExpression = "(billDate.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)"
comNewColName = "nextMonthFirstOfBillDate"
```

This is just calculate next month first date of billDate.

```
df = df.assign(comNewColName=lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x['billDate']).replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)))
```

What I am trying to do: next month first date of billDate and rename the column as "nextMonthFirstOfBillDate".

Comment: Can I ask how you coded yourself into a situation where this is necessary?

Comment: I need to calculate kpis on the received csv data. the kpis are defined in a json file. It read the json file. It need to calculate based on the defined in that json.

Comment: Hi, could you please include a small subset of your data as a copyable piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the provided data?